# Is there any way to prevent COM imported interface from throwing a COMException?

Tags: c#, interface, com, comexception

I have declared a COM interface, `IFileDialog`, and everything works fine but, there is this one annoying thing, if the dialog is closed or canceled, after calling `int Show([Optional] IntPtr owner);`, a HRESULT isn't returned, instead a COMException is being thrown. Is there any way to prevent this?

Initially wanted to write a method as:

```
public DialogResult Show()
{
    // _value = IFileDialog
    return (_value.Show() == 0) ? DialogResult.Ok : DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

but am forced to write it as:

```
public DialogResult Show()
{
    try
    {
        return (_value.Show() == 0) ? DialogResult.Ok : DialogResult.Cancel; //incase it goes threw and a exception isn't thrown
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Note: this isn't a big issue, just am not keen on using `try catch`

Comment: Are you looking for the [PreserveSig] attribute? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig?view=netframework-4.8 otherwise please show how you define IFileDialog.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog_Vista_Interop.cs,3f577805f087ca6c